# How to integrate solr suggester in solrnet with external source location?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I've refereed [this](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/SpellChecking)  link and trying to implement and got an error "Bad Request".
What could be the reason?
or Is there any tutorial out there that will helpful to implement it? or
How to integrate solr suggester in solrnet with external source location?

Here is SolrConfig.xml:

```
 <searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">suggest</str>
  <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
  <!-- Alternatives to lookupImpl: 
       org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.FSTLookup   [finite state automaton]
       org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.WFSTLookupFactory [weighted finite state automaton]
       org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.jaspell.JaspellLookup [default, jaspell-based]
       org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup   [ternary trees]
  -->
  <str name="field">Name</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
  <str name="field">ManufacturerName</str>
  <str name="field">CategoryName</str>
  <str name="field">ShortDescription</str>
  <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
<bool name="exactMatchFirst">true</bool>
  <str name="sourceLocation">source.txt</str>

</lst>
```

true
      suggest
      true
      5
      true
    
    
      suggest

Here is Code:

`private static ISolrOperations<SolrCustomProduct> solrCustomWorker;`

`ISolrQueryResults<SolrCustomProduct> results;`

```
//Check connection instance invoked or not
if (solrCustomWorker == null)
{
    Startup.Init<SolrCustomProduct>(solrURL);
    solrCustomWorker = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SolrCustomProduct>>();
}
```

`results = solrCustomWorker.Query("ac", new QueryOptions
             {
                 SpellCheck = new SpellCheckingParameters { Collate=true},
             });`

Here is Log:

```
    Sep 15, 2012 10:13:59 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field text
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1330)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:408)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrIndexAnalyzer.reusableTokenStream(IndexSchema.java:383)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.getFieldQuery(QueryParser.java:574)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrQueryParser.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1429)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1317)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1245)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1234)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParserPlugin.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 15, 2012 10:13:59 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [core-live] webapp=/solr path=/select params={spellcheck=true&q=ac&?=&spellcheck.collate=true&rows=100000000} status=400 QTime=1 
Sep 15, 2012 10:14:08 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field text
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1330)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:408)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrIndexAnalyzer.reusableTokenStream(IndexSchema.java:383)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.getFieldQuery(QueryParser.java:574)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrQueryParser.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1429)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1317)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1245)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1234)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParserPlugin.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 15, 2012 10:14:08 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [core-live] webapp=/solr path=/select params={spellcheck=true&q=ac&?=&spellcheck.collate=true&rows=100000000} status=400 QTime=1 
Sep 15, 2012 10:14:10 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field text
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1330)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:408)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrIndexAnalyzer.reusableTokenStream(IndexSchema.java:383)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.getFieldQuery(QueryParser.java:574)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrQueryParser.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1429)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1317)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1245)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1234)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParserPlugin.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 15, 2012 10:14:10 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [core-live] webapp=/solr path=/select params={spellcheck=true&q=ac&?=&spellcheck.collate=true&rows=100000000} status=400 QTime=1
```

Comment: Could you provide some of your solr suggester configuration,  a sample of the solrnet code you are using to perform your query and the log output entry for the bad request from your server hosting your solr instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a default search field defined as `text` somewhere in your configuration. Most likely in the `/select` request handler as seen below. See the `<str name="df">text</str>` entry.

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
       will be overridden by parameters in the request
    -->
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <int name="rows">10</int>
     <str name="df">text</str>
   </lst>

   ....
</requestHandler>
```

Since you do not have a field named `text` defined in your schema.xml this is why you are seeing this error. Most likely, you have not seen this error previously, b/c you were either specifying the fields to search against explicitly or using a different request handler. But now when you are searching against the spellchecker it is using the `/select` request handler.

Update the `<str name="df">text</str>` entry to be a valid default field for your schema or remove it completely and specify the field to search in the query. More information on the [df](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#df) parameter from the Solr Wiki.